# confirmation email is send from my local host registration of a user but mail will not display in there email account?

Tags: login, email

I am creating a forums for discussion website in this i used bbpress registration login page or signup but problem is that the mail confirmation is display by filling all detail of a user but the  registration password link will not display on user mail account.
                         I am using local host for run  a website.please give me a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_mail` uses php `mail()` function, which does not work on localhost. Since SMTP server does not exist on localhost.

For `mail()` to work on localhost you'll have to setup SMTP on your local server.
Or use some SMTP plugin which will bypass `mail()' and connect to SMTP.

Comment: thank you.....  but here is some error by testing it from test mail

Comment: error Test Message Sent
The result was:
bool(false)

Comment: Test Message Sent
The result was:
bool(false)